# java web app memory heap needed

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

I need to upload 3 war applications on the server space i rent. Right now the heap size I am paying for is 128mb. By just uploading the 3 war files I get a message showing 228/128 mb are being used (so I guess I am exceeding the mbs) but 2 out 3 can run simultaneously. I tried to run the "Profile Project" in Netbeans (for only one of my applications) and I get a graph flunctuating between 100mb and 450mb.

How I am I going to determine how much memory heap I need?
Moreover what happens when multiple users need to access the application at he same time? Will I need more memory heap then?

Comment: Have you tried deploying the applications on a local Tomcat instance and profiling the memory usage there?

Comment: You determine that by doing proper load testing. If you estimate that on average 10 concurrent users will be using your application, then test with 20 concurrent users. Then you take the maximum memory usage you see and add about half that amount to be safe when you hit a rare peak moment.